# Laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: laravel, api, request, postman

I have Laravel project works as an API, On my local machine it's working currectly but when I uploaded it on the server and send a request with Postman it doesn't send a post request, It's changed to GET request ! I read so many solutions and nothing worked for me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiEOm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTFV6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDxD5.jpg

My .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]



    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of postman - exactly what you are sending and the response you receive.

Comment: Please share your route file and on what URL are you sending the request (Postman's screenshot would be nice too)

Comment: I Added screenshots